# How to test Ok() result using MStest in ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, mstest, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using MStest for testing my controllers.

I want to test this action:

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetGroups")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var groups = await _unitOfWork.Repository<Groupe>().GetAllAsync();
    var groupsDto = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<GroupDto>>(groups);
    if (groupsDto.Count() == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(groupsDto);
}
```

One of the test for this action looks like that:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Group_Get_Should_Return_InstanceOfTypeOkNegotiatedContentResultIEnumerableGroupDto()
{
    // Arrange
    moqGroupRepository.Setup(g => g.GetAllAsync(null)).ReturnsAsync(groups).Verifiable();
    moqUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.Repository<Groupe>()).Returns(moqGroupRepository.Object);

    var controller = new GroupController(moqUnitOfWork.Object);

    // Act
    var actionResult = await controller.Get() as OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<GroupDto>>;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actionResult, typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<GroupDto>>));
}
```

The problem here is **OkNegotiatedContentResult** is unknown in ASP.Net Core project test.

What should I use to test `Ok()` result?

Comment: You should not have to test the controller. It doesn't really do anything. Just test the results from the repo.

Comment: @illug, how about testing return type, i think it's important.

Comment: I dont think that is relevant, Not the return from the controller but from the repo yes. One of the nice things with DI is the ability to not test the controllers. You'll have issues if you need to authenticate as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The probleme here is OkNegotiatedContentResult is unknow in asp net
>   core project test What should i use to test Ok() result?

You could fix the problem by installing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` NuGet package where implementations of `IActionResult` are defined.

However ASP.NET Core does not contain `OkNegotiatedContentResult` type, it's from ASP.NET Web API. In ASP.NET Core `Controller.Ok()` method returns the instance of `OkObjectResult` type.

You also have inconsistent checks in these two statements:

```
var actionResult = await controller.Get() as OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<GroupDto>>;
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actionResult, typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<GroupDto>>));
```

`as` operator will return `null` if object could not be cast to requested type. So you could replace the second check with the following:

```
Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult);
```

So the required steps are:

1. Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` NuGet package to your Test project.
2. Adjust the test code in the following way:

   ```
   // ...
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

   [TestMethod]
   public async Task Group_Get_Should_Return_InstanceOfTypeOkNegotiatedContentResultIEnumerableGroupDto()
   {
       // Arrange
       moqGroupRepository.Setup(g => g.GetAllAsync(null)).ReturnsAsync(groups).Verifiable();
       moqUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.Repository<Groupe>()).Returns(moqGroupRepository.Object);

       var controller = new GroupController(moqUnitOfWork.Object);

       // Act
       var actionResult = await controller.Get() as OkObjectResult;

       // Assert
       Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult);
       Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actionResult.Value, typeof(IEnumerable<GroupDto>));
   }
   ```

Comment: Use `Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);` as per docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Yes, but if result is of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Result.OkObjectResult then some issue with privacy happens

Answer (score 1):

Code Fuller's post helps. The last Assert should be a little different, maybe because we are on 3.0 now:

```
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(IEnumerable<GroupDto>), actionResult.Value);
```